# Implementing minimax algorithm into tic-tac-toe using c#

Tags: c#, minimax

I am trying to implement the minimax algorithm into a tic-tac-toe game, where the computer will play the optimal move based on the minimax algorithm. I have written the whole algorithm but get weird and seemingly random moves by the AI. For example, when the tic-tac-toe board
is laid out like shown:

> ```
> ' ' 'o' 'x'
> ' ' 'o' ' '
> 'x' ' ' ' '
> ```

The Minimax algorithm then chooses the first spot, which is obviously not the optimal choice:

> ```
> 'o' 'o' 'x'
> ' ' 'o' ' '
> 'x' ' ' ' '
> ```

Here is my code:

```
namespace MinimaxAlg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[,] board = { { '-', 'o', 'x'},
                              { '-', 'o', '-'},
                              { 'x', '-', '-'} };

            int bestScore = int.MinValue;
            int moveI = -1;
            int moveJ = -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (board[i, j] == '-')
                    {
                        board[i, j] = 'o';
                        var score = Minimax(board, 'o');
                        board[i, j] = '-';

                        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + score);
                        Console.WriteLine("BestScore: " + bestScore);


                        if (score > bestScore)
                        {
                            bestScore = score;
                            moveI = i;
                            moveJ = j;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            board[moveI, moveJ] = 'p';

            foreach (var i in board)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        static int Minimax(char[,] board, char forWho)
        {
            if (CheckWhoWins(board, forWho))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (forWho == 'o')
            {
                var bestScore = int.MinValue;
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        if (board[i, j] == '-')
                        {
                            board[i, j] = forWho;
                            var score = Minimax(board, 'x');
                            board[i, j] = '-';

                            bestScore = Math.Max(bestScore, score);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return bestScore;
            }
            else
            {
                var bestScore = int.MaxValue;
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        if (board[i, j] == '-')
                        {
                            board[i, j] = forWho;
                            var score = Minimax(board, 'o');
                            board[i, j] = '-';

                            bestScore = Math.Min(bestScore, score);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return bestScore;
            }
        }


        static bool CheckWhoWins(char[,] board, char forWho)
        {
            if ((board[0, 0] == forWho && board[0, 1] == forWho && board[0, 2] == forWho) || (board[1, 0] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[1, 2] == forWho) ||
                (board[2, 0] == forWho && board[2, 1] == forWho && board[2, 2] == forWho) || (board[0, 0] == forWho && board[1, 0] == forWho && board[2, 0] == forWho) ||
                (board[0, 1] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[2, 1] == forWho) || (board[0, 2] == forWho && board[1, 2] == forWho && board[2, 2] == forWho) ||
                (board[0, 0] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[0, 0] == forWho) || (board[0, 2] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[2, 0] == forWho))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea of what might be wrong, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it does that because it knows it will win anyways. You need to update the scoring method so that the AI prefers shorter winning games over longer winning games.

Comment: @user3386109 - Excellent observation!

Comment: @Enigmativity I had the same bug when I first implemented minimax ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues in your code.

First up, a simple typo. One of your conditions for the win is `board[0, 0] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[0, 0] == forWho`. Clearly the last one should be `board[2, 2]`.

Secondly, you're giving `o` two goes straight away. These lines show it:

```
board[i, j] = 'o';
var score = Minimax(board, 'o');
```

The second line should be `var score = Minimax(board, 'x');`.

Finally, user3386109 nailed it. You're giving a long game the same score as a short game.

If we change the scoring system to give bigger scores for the least moves then it works just fine.

```
static int CheckWhoWins(char[,] board, char forWho)
{
    if ((board[0, 0] == forWho && board[0, 1] == forWho && board[0, 2] == forWho)
        || (board[1, 0] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[1, 2] == forWho)
        || (board[2, 0] == forWho && board[2, 1] == forWho && board[2, 2] == forWho)
        || (board[0, 0] == forWho && board[1, 0] == forWho && board[2, 0] == forWho)
        || (board[0, 1] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[2, 1] == forWho)
        || (board[0, 2] == forWho && board[1, 2] == forWho && board[2, 2] == forWho)
        || (board[0, 0] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[2, 2] == forWho)
        || (board[0, 2] == forWho && board[1, 1] == forWho && board[2, 0] == forWho))
    {
        var score = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == '-')
                {
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

`Minimax` (which should be just `MinMax`) is now:

```
static int Minimax(char[,] board, char forWho)
{
    var score = CheckWhoWins(board, forWho);
    if (score != 0)
    {
        return score;
    }

    if (forWho == 'o')
    {
        var bestScore = int.MinValue;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == '-')
                {
                    board[i, j] = forWho;
                    var currentScore = Minimax(board, 'x');
                    board[i, j] = '-';

                    bestScore = Math.Max(bestScore, currentScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
    else
    {
        var bestScore = int.MaxValue;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == '-')
                {
                    board[i, j] = forWho;
                    var currentScore = Minimax(board, 'o');
                    board[i, j] = '-';

                    bestScore = Math.Min(bestScore, currentScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
}
```

When you run this you get the following result:

[image: board]

---

And for bonus points, in my opinion, here's a slightly better version of `Minimax`:

```
static int Minimax(char[,] board, char forWho)
{
    var score = CheckWhoWins(board, forWho);
    if (score != 0)
    {
        return score;
    }

    var bestScore = forWho == 'o' ? int.MinValue : int.MaxValue;

    int CalcBest(int x, int y) => (forWho == 'o' ? x > y : y > x) ? x : y;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i, j] == '-')
            {
                board[i, j] = forWho;
                var currentScore = Minimax(board, forWho == 'o' ? 'x' : 'o');
                board[i, j] = '-';

                bestScore = CalcBest(bestScore, currentScore);
            }
        }
    }
    return bestScore;
}
```